# How to implement CRC u8()SUM in python

Tags: python, crc

First of all, I have no experience with CRC. I want to talk to a solar charge controller via Serial in python. The request is 8 Bytes long. The [Communication protocoll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuyH8.png) requires that I send in Byte[5] and byte[6] (8 bits of information) for the CRC. But what do these 8 bits mean? Do they represent the generator polynom? Can I choose the bits?

In the response of the charge controller I once again get 8 bits of information from the CRC (from the charge controller). But what do I do with this CRC?

I have 8 bits which I sent and 8 which I received. I don't know what to do with these. Is there a python module for the CRC?

Comment: Is there any more information provided about what CRC is used? Or maybe a link to the controller manual?

Comment: It looks like an 8-bit check value is calculated on bytes 1..4. The check value is split into two 4-bit pieces and put in bytes 5 and 6 as shown. On the other end, the same calculation is done and then compared to what is in bytes 5 and 6 to verify the integrity of the message. There is no way to know how to actually do that calculation without either a specification or a bunch of examples of those packets.